# how to toggle input box based select option in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am trying to add an input box to the DOM based on the user selection:

option1 other option 3 otherwise remove input box from dom, how can do it, i tried bellow code but it is not working?

```
html--

<select ng-model="myDropDown">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>    <p ng-if="myDropDown=='two' || ans=='three'">
   <input type="text" ng-model="fname" name="fname" />
</p>
```

jsFiddle-->http://jsfiddle.net/EZbfM/717/

Comment: it is visible to dom right inside style="display:none", ng-if is true that i want apend inut box to DOM , ng-if is false then i want remove completely from DOM input box, please help me any one

Answer (score 2):

The reason `ng-if` is behaving unexpectedly is because you seem to have referenced an ancient version of AngularJS (1.0.2). If you update it to a more recent version, ng-if will work as expected.

See the link here for the issue related to the evaluation issue of `ng-if`: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4005

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show it when the dropdown is on one or on three, otherwise not?

change

```
<input ng-if="myDropDown=='two'" type="text">
```

to

```
 <input ng-hide="myDropDown=='two'" type="text">
```

It will always render then, but only show if the option chosen is one or three

Comment: it is visible to dom right inside style="display:none", ng-if is true that i want  apend inut box to DOM , ng-if is false then i want remove completely from DOM input box

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are trying to display an element based on myDropDown value. You can write complex expressions as `&&` or `||` in `ng-show` with the following synthax:

```
<div ng-show="myDropDown == 'two' || myDropDown == 'three'">
    <!-- Will be displayed only when you select 'two' or 'three' -->
    <input type="text" ng-model="fname"/>
</div>
```

#### [Fiddle with `ng-show`](http://jsfiddle.net/57yhoLsc/)

#### [Fiddle with `ng-if`](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/5945d1r9/)

Comment: it is visible to dom right inside style="display:none", ng-if is true that i want apend inut box to DOM , ng-if is false then i want remove completely from DOM input box, please tell me only i want use ng-if

Comment: @ramesh1226 As the selection may change, it is better, in terms of performance, to use `ng-show` *in this specific case* instead. It avoid the user to create/delete/create/delete elements in the DOM

Comment: @ramesh1226 Anyway, it works the same with ng-if. Note that you will need Angular 1.1+ (for example [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vk6hbfc/) works in 1.5).

Comment: ng-show , in-hide uses , input box will show like this display :none / block, i don't want this , i need input box completly remove from DOM, that is posible only ng-if, how can i do it

Comment: @ramesh1226 See my previous comment + my updated answer. I've made Fiddle **that works with ng-if** and removed the element from the DOM. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: @ramesh1226 Just to make the Fiddle runnable. You don't need the JS part of the Fiddle: only the HTML one I've provided in my answer. [**Same Fiddle without JS**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/5945d1r9/).

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29387/)**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="myDropDown">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
  </select>    
  <p ng-if="myDropDown=='two' || myDropDown=='three'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="fname" name="fname" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fine..

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.myDropDown = "one";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div>
    <select data-ng-model="myDropDown">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
    
    <p> 
    <input ng-model="comment" ng-if="myDropDown != 'two'" type="text"> </p>
</div>
</body>
```